# Is there any default tool in OSX by which to add text (such as subtitle) to a video?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, video-editing

I would like to add a notification to a video at some particular time period that "Mistake  Lorem in this".

**Does OSX have any default video tool (simple) to add any type of text (subtitle ok too) to the video?**

Comment: Have you attempted to do this with iMovie?  Technically it's not part of OS X but it IS included with all Macs, at least for the last 9 years or so.  Before that it was bundled with Macs or free to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, I did not mean to have subtitles but change mistakes and correct them. 
My friend says the best tool here is **Premier** (Adobe). 
He says that iMovie is difficult to use.

Answer (score 2):

Another one that isn't built into OSX but [Subler](https://code.google.com/p/subler/) is an excellent, small, and free program for adding .srt files to existing video (in multiple codecs).

Answer (score 1):

iMovie may work for you.

Import your Movie and then.

1,  Select the Titles in the Content library to pick Title theme

2, Drag the Subtitle Theme down to the movie strip.

3, Adjust the Subtitle time line to where you want it and duration.

4, Write you text in the text field.

5, Set your text style.

---

[image]

[Open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpdHG.jpg)

---

Answer (score 1):

If your video is in mp4 format, you can embed SRT subtitles to video using Subler. It's a free software.

If your video is not in mp4 format, you should go to Subtitle Writer on Mac App Store. It's an paid app for $4.99.

Both Subler and Subtitle Writer are making subtitle track in video so that Quicktime Player X or iOS devices can show them as Closed Caption.

If you just want to make few comments on video, you can make it in iMovie.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't built-in to OS X, but perhaps [this $9 tool](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/24830/submerge) might be what you're looking for.

Just looking for subtitles? Then look no further than [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/)

If you need something free, built-in to OS X (and you have programing chops), perhaps OS X's Core Video and Automator are worth a look too.

Or can you be more specific?